# Why does decltype(auto) return a reference here?

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, decltype

I think (thought) I understand `auto`. Same about `decltype`. However, in C++14, one can have some thing like `decltype(auto)` as the return type of a function. Consider the following:

```
decltype(auto) foo()
{
    int m = 1;
    return m;
}
```

The return type is `int`, everything makes sense.

However,

```
decltype(auto) foo()
{
    int m = 1;
    return (m);
}
```

returns `int&` (i.e. reference to `int`).

I have absolutely NO IDEA why this happens, why do these parentheses make any difference at all!? Hope someone can shed some light on this.

PS: I've also tagged with `c++` as there are many more people that check the `c++` tag than `c++14`.

Comment: Because `decltype((m))` is also an lvalue-reference.

Comment: I thought so, so putting parenthesis around makes it an lvalue? I.e., if I do `return (Foo())`, is it considered as returning a reference to `Foo()`?

Comment: @vsoftco no, the rules for `decltype(e)` depend on whether `e` is parenthesized or not. That doesn't mean adding parentheses elsewhere has that kind of effect

Comment: The rules say that a bare identifier does not result in an lvalue, but any other lvalue expression does. So putting parentheses around a bare identifier turns it into an "other" lvalue expression. `Foo()` is not a bare identifier, so the parens make no difference.

Comment: @kek, thanks, I understand what's going on now.

Comment: Because `decltype` stinks. And people complained about `static` being overloaded!

Comment: c++23 has a breaking change by [P2266](https://wg21.link/P2266R3). Now `decltype(auto)` with `return (m)`, changes from returns `int&` to `int&&` by the move-eligible context added by `P2266`. While the unparenthesized rules of `decltype(auto)` are still strong, the `decltype(auto)` with `return m` still returns `int` as always. That is the unparenthesized returns of `decltype(auto)` remains unaffected by P2266 move-eligible context.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]

> 4. For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows:
>      — if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>      — otherwise, if e is an xvalue, decltype(e) is T&&, where T is the type of e;
>      — otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;
>      — otherwise, decltype(e) is the type of e.

In your example you have `return (m)` so `e` is `(m)`. That is not an unparenthesized id-expression or class member access, so we go to the second bullet. It is not an xvalue so we go to the third bullet. It is an lvalue, so the type is `T&` where `T` is `int`.

Comment: spot on, the only thing I don't get is why putting `(...)` makes `decltype` thinks it has an lvalue

Comment: `m` is already an lvalue, and `(m)` is also an lvalue. The point is that the parentheses alter how `decltype` makes it deduce the type. Without the double parentheses you just get the type of `m`, with double parentheses you get either T&& or T& depending whether `m` is an lvalue or rvalue (and in your example it's an lvalue)

Comment: That's what I don't get: first line in your answer: "if e is an unparenthesized ..." implies `decltype(m)` deduces `int`. Third line, `if e is an lvalue...`, implies `int&`. However, in the first case, `e` (or `m` in my case) is also an lvalue, but because it doesn't have parenthesis is deduced as a non-reference? I gotta say that the standard is a bit confusing, but is this what's happening?

Comment: Yes. `decltype(m)` is the type of `m` but `decltype((m))` is a reference to the type of `m`. By the standards of the standard this is really quite straightforward. I'm not sure what part you don't get.

Comment: Ok, got it, for some reason the third line "otherwise, if e is an lvalue..." made me think that is like an if/else structure, and what was before was not a `lvalue`. Thanks!

Comment: No, you go through the bullets in order and stop at the first one that is true (note the "otherwise" at the end of each bullet)

Comment: Yes, makes sense now. I gotta say I'm not too familiar with the C++ standard, although I try to catch on :)

Comment: What I don't get is *why* (what does it enables that wouldn't be possible otherwise?). There's surely a logical explanation, and I would be interested to learn more about it (a tweet about this post is currently being mass-retweeted, so many people might be interested as well).

Comment: The rule I quoted for `decltype(e)` already existed in C++11, so the `decltype(auto)` rules are the same for consistency (see [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html): "It occurs to me that the difference in meaning of `decltype` depending on the form of the expression (e.g. parenthesized or not) might be more surprising in this context, but I think it would be even more surprising if this worked differently from C++11 `decltype`.") The C++11 rule was introduced in [N2115](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2115.pdf), without explanation

Comment: In essence it allows two different queries to be made with decltype, asking either "what is the type if this variable" or "what is the type and value category (lvalue/rvalue) of this expression". The extra parentheses are the syntax for the latter.

Comment: Was just reading Scott Meyer’s book and encountered this. My immediate reaction was what happens if your function has two return statements (something I abhor but is allowed) one of which has the argument in parentheses and the other doesn’t?

Comment: @David if the return statements have the same type, that's the type the function returns. If they don't have the same type, the function won't compile. That's just the same as `return 1;` and `return 2U;` in a function with a deduced return type: you can't do that.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for that. It's what I suspected but there's something "creepily" wrong about the concept of parenthesis changing the meaning of something like that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely We can if the different types are in different branches of an `if constexpr` ;)

Comment: Please update the answer for the c++23 move-eligible context [P2266](https://wg21.link/P2266R3). I just wonder why the [unparenthesized bullet](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype) of `decltype(auto)` is more prioritised than [\[expr.prim.id.unqual\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#4) by P2266. Please clearify this also. Both `gcc13` and `clang13` have already [implemented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) this, the godbolting is very much welcome.