# Why doesn't decltype(auto) return the address of the lvalue?

Tags: c++, decltype, perfect-forwarding, decltype-auto

I have the following code

```
decltype(auto) foo(){
    int a = 10;
    return a;
}
```

I would have expected the type of foo to be

```
int & foo()
```

because the *a* is an lvalue and decltype(a) is a reference.

If I do a very similar thing but obfuscate it with a perfect forwarding lambda I get a different result.

```
// perfect forwarding lambda
auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(i)>(i); };

decltype(auto) foo(){

    int a = 10;
    return identity(a);
}
```

the return type of foo become `int&`

Can anybody enlighten me on the exactly rules for what is happening here?

Comment: In the case without the *identity* function the return type of foo is ``int`` and with the perfect forwarding lambda it is ``int &``

Comment: Even if the return type of `foo` was a reference, that would make you return a reference to a local variable, a variable whose life-time ends when the function returns making the reference immediately invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Don't read the question as me wanting to return the address of a local variable. This is what I'm trying to avoid. I have some template spaghetti which when resolved ends up with the following puzzle. With the *identity* function I get a ref return and without it I get an rvalue return. The question is what are the rules that make this so.

Comment: @songyuanyao Godbolt says the return of foo is an rvalue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493105/why-doesnt-decltypeauto-return-the-address-of-the-lvalue ???

Comment: `decltype` has a special meaning when it is applied to an *id-expression*. [Cf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557369/why-does-decltypeauto-return-a-reference-here): `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))`.

Comment: `decltype(a)` is `int`, not `int&`. To get `int&` you have to enclose `a` into parentheses `decltype((a))` gives you `int&`.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Sorry I misread your question.

Comment: Side note: If you *really* wanted a *dangling(!)* reference you could do `return (a);` – the one example why placing parentheses around return values in general is wrong...

Comment: @rafix07 interesting. If I change the definition of my identity lambda to ```auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype((i))>(i); };``` I now get the same result between both versions.

Comment: Then please try to come up with a better example. Such problems and other unrelated errors tend to distract from the actual problem being asked about.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What unrelated errors are distracting you? The issue at hand has been clarified that there is a significant difference betwen ``auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype((i))>(i); };`` and ``auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(i)>(i); };`` when creating an identity function.

Answer (score -1):

The critical difference as that I had written the identity function incorrectly.

```
auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { 
   return std::forward<decltype(i)>(i); 
};
```

is not the same as

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) identity(T && v){
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

the correct implementation of identity as a lambda is

```
auto identity = [](auto&& i) -> decltype(auto) { 
   return std::forward<decltype((i))>(i); 
};
```

Note the double set of brackets `decltype((i))`