# Does the type of std::vector<int>::iterator change when you increment it with '++'?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, c++-concepts

I'm experimenting with C++20 concepts and I've hit a strange problem I can't explain.

I'm trying to define a `concept` that checks a given iterator can be incremented (fine), and also checks that the type doesn't change as a result (not fine).

Forgive my ignorance, what am I missing? The final line of the error states:

' note: ‘++ it’ does not satisfy return-type-requirement
{ ++it } -> std::same_as; '

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename Iter>
concept Iterable = requires(Iter it){
    { ++it } // Check iterator can be incremented (compiles but does not check return type)
    { ++it } -> std::same_as<Iter>; // Also check the return type (**fails**)
};

template<typename Iter>
requires Iterable<Iter>
void doesNothing(Iter current, Iter end){
    while(current != end){
        ++current;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    doesNothing(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```

A big thank you in advance.

I expected the line:

```cpp
{ ++it } -> std::same_as<Iter>;
```

To 'pipe' the return of `{++it}` into the template `std::same_as<T, U>` resulting in `std::same_as<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>` which would of course be accepted.

Edit: Barry's excellent answer pertains to this: [Why does decltype(auto) return a reference here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557369/why-does-decltypeauto-return-a-reference-here)

Comment: C++ is statically typed language, so your current title is very confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I expected the line:
>
> ```cpp
> { ++it } -> std::same_as<Iter>;
> ```
>
> To 'pipe' the return of `{++it}` into the template `std::same_as<T, U>` resulting in `std::same_as<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>` which would of course be accepted.

You're half right.

The meaning of `{ ++it } -> std::same_as<Iter>` is that we're checking that `++it` is a valid expression and that `std::same_as<decltype((++it)), Iter>` holds, that's correct.

But `decltype((+it))` isn't `Iter`. It's `Iter&`. That's why your check is failing.

Which is why [`std::weakly_incrementable`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#concept:weakly_incrementable) is specified as:

```cpp
template<class I>
  concept weakly_incrementable =
    movable<I> &&
    requires(I i) {
      typename iter_difference_t<I>;
      requires is-signed-integer-like<iter_difference_t<I>>;
      { ++i } -> same_as<I&>;   // not required to be equality-preserving
      i++;                      // not required to be equality-preserving
    };
```

Comment: Do you know why we get the extra parentheses in the `decltype((++it))` call, as opposed to `decltype(++it)`? As I understand the latter would resolve to a non-reference type.

Comment: @DaveWoodward The extra parentheses don't matter in this case, both `decltype(++it)` and `decltype((++it))` are the same - they give you `Iter&`. Where they differ is when the expression is just the name of a variable. In that case, `decltype(it)` is `Iter` while `decltype((it))` is `Iter&` (because it's an lvalue).